# Check if an integer is present in a linear recurrence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

Given the following recurrence relation :

$f(n) = 5f(n-1) - 2f(n-2)$ where $f(0) = 0, f(1) = 1$

I need to find out if an integer $F_n$ is present in the sequence in $O(1)$ time and space.

Solving the equation, there are two distinct real roots.

$\phi = \frac{5 + \sqrt17}2$

$\psi = \frac{5 - \sqrt17}2$

Therefore, $F_n = \frac{\phi^n - \psi^n}{\sqrt17}$

Similar to Binet's rearranged formula, I want to solve for $n$ in terms of $F_n$.

Since, $\psi = \frac{2}{\phi}$

$\sqrt17F_n = \phi^n - \frac{2^n}{\phi^n}$

$Or,$

$\phi^{2n} - \sqrt17F_n\phi^n-2^n = 0$

Here I'm not able to find out a solution to express $n$ purely in terms of $F_n$ so that I can calculate the perfect square just like in Binet's formula.

Comment: Your going to run into trouble with $O(1)$ because your integers don’t have size $O(1)$ anymore. In computer science we say $O(1)$ cuz there’s an implicit assumption on how big a number is ever allowed to get. All the O(1)s you see in computer science are really $O(n)$ where $n$ is the number of digits of the numbers they are operating on. Assuming this is satisfactory I’ll see if I can find an answer to this.

Comment: Yes I can understand what you are saying with respect to assembly code/ISA. But I'm more interested in the mathematical solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice how *small* $\psi \approx 0.44$ is. So in the expression

$$F_n = \frac{\phi^n - \psi^n}{\sqrt{17}}$$

$\phi^n$ is doing *all* of the work. After all, $0 \leq \psi^n \leq \left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )^n$.

So at least eventually, $F_n = \left \lceil \frac{\phi^n}{\sqrt{17}} \right \rceil$. Some quick computation will show whether this is always true, or if you'll need to have finitely many special cases. Of course, you can handle finitely many special cases without breaking $O(1)$ time/space.

This makes your job substantially easier. As now $F_n \approx \frac{\phi^n}{\sqrt{17}}$, and so some quick algebra gives

$$n \approx \log_\phi \left ( \sqrt{17} F_n \right ).$$

So given any $k$, we have a *possible* value of $n$. Namely, look at $m$ the nearest integer to $\log_\phi \left ( \sqrt{17} k \right )$. Then we can ask if $F_m$ really *does* equal $k$.

Both of these steps can be done in $O(1)$ space and time (at least if we use the common lie that real-valued arithmetic is constant time), as desired.

(Caveat Lector: I didn't check if you found these $\phi$ and $\psi$ correctly. So the specifics might change based on that. The idea should still work, though).

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: $F_n = \frac{\phi^n - \psi^n}{\sqrt17}$ and not $\frac{\phi^n + \psi^n}{\sqrt17}$

Comment: Woops! Good catch. I'm editing the answer now ^_^

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution is working perfectly. Really proud that my post will be the first one in the internet to solve this unique problem, before this which I have found no one else.  Even though this solution assumes some approximations, using Python's ceil function and double division operator, things are working smooth even with loss of precision. I guess my employer really wanted to see my skills in recursion or memoization (DP) but he/she should be more delighted with this solution.

Comment: Anyways here's my Python code : [Gist](https://gist.github.com/roychowdhuryrohit-dev/e05f92af45a8df6d78afa16ab5853b72#file-recurrence-py-L4)